# Inputs of a transformer model

Tags: nlp, sequence, transformer-model, attention-model

I am trying to understand the transformer model. Please consider my below example and help me to understand the concept.

Example: English to french conversion

My questions:

1. Is the input word embedding is an English- french pretrained embedding?
2. In which step of the decoder the prediction of a french word is happening?
3. Is output embedding in decoder is just decoder's output till predicted, if so why should I mask the next word since that is unknown to me as I still yet not passed as output

Please clarify me this doubt

I also referred to these links:

- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/81727/what-would-be-the-target-input-for-transformer-decoder-during-test-phase
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51785/what-is-the-first-input-to-the-decoder-in-a-transformer-model

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I refer to the original paper [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) by Vaswani et al..

1. The input is transformed into the matrix. For this purpose, a Word embedding layer is used, which can be thought of as a lookup table.
2. The encoder creates a representation matrix in one shot.
   This is then the input for the decoder. So the matrix **V** and **K** which is used in the decoder is the representation of the input.
3. The encoder already knows the total input in advance. To avoid cheating, the words still to be processed are masked so that the encoder cannot "cheat".